# AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm getting this error from Django when I tried creating a custom authentication system. I'm pretty sure this is coming from my views.py but I have no idea how to fix it. All the code I worked on is down below. I did some print statements to see if the code breaks somewhere and I found that `authenticate(request, user=user)` in views.py stops the code which causes auth.py and managers.py to not trigger.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Internet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Internet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Internet\Desktop\Programming\Discord\Ξ X 0 Website\Ξ X 0 Dashboard\dashboard\home\views.py", line 12, in home_view
    authenticate(request, user=user)
  File "C:\Users\Internet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 80, in authenticate
    user.backend = backend_path
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

**managers.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth import models

class DiscordUserOAuth2Manager(models.UserManager):
    def create_new_discord_user(self, user):
        print('Inside Discord User Manager')
        discord_tag = '%s#%s' % (user['username'], user['discriminator'])
        new_user = self.create(
            id=user['id'],
            avatar=user['avatar'],
            public_flags=user['public_flags'],
            flags=user['flags'],
            locale=user['locale'],
            mfa_enabled=user['mfa_enabled'],
            discord_tag=discord_tag
        )
        return new_user
```

**auth.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from .models import DiscordUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DiscordAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, user):
        find_user = DiscordUser.objects.filter(id=user['id'])
        if len(find_user) == 0:
            print("User was not found. Saving...")
            new_user = DiscordUser.objects.create_new_discord_user
            (user)
            print(new_user)
            return new_user
        return find_user
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from .managers import DiscordUserOAuth2Manager

class DiscordUser(models.Model):
    objects = DiscordUserOAuth2Manager()

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    discord_tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    public_flags = models.BigIntegerField()
    flag = models.IntegerField()
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mfa_enabled = models.BooleanField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
import requests

client_id = "my_id"

def home_view(request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    user = exchange_code(code)
    authenticate(request, user=user)
    return render(request, "home.html", {})

def exchange_code(code: str):
    data = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": "my_secret",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/home/",
        "scope": "identify guilds"
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    response = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=headers)
    credentials = response.json()
    
    access_token = credentials['access_token']
    response = requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me', headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    })
    print(response)
    user = response.json()
    print(user)
    return user
```

**settings.py**

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'home.auth.DiscordAuthenticationBackend'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a user instance in the backends `authenticate` method you are returning a QuerySet (collection) of users, giving you an error. So your backend should look like:

```py
class DiscordAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, user):
        try:
            return_user = DiscordUser.objects.get(id=user['id'])
        except DiscordUser.DoesNotExist:
            print("User was not found. Saving...")
            return_user = DiscordUser.objects.create_new_discord_user(user)
            print(new_user)
        return return_user
```

> **Note**: Ideally your function `exchange_code` **should** be part of the backend here since it deals with authenticating the user from some
> code / key. Your `authenticate` method should accept the code as the
> credentials instead of a dictionary of the user details.